# Service fabric stateful service - cancellation token is not set to true when service deleted

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, cancellation-token

I have a `StatefulService` which in the `RunAsync()` method creates some tasks (using `Task.Run()`), but not awaits them.
I have a strange issue that when I try to manually delete the service in the cluster, and I am in debug mode at VS, the cancellation token value is not set to true, and RunAsync() continues to execute. Then, getting the following warning in cluster UI:

```
The api ireplicator.changerole(n) on node is stuck
```

Yes, it is stuck, but it only because SF didn't send a cancellation request.

Now, the wierdest thing is that it happens from time to time, and I cant track the reason for it.
And as you can see, I am honoring the cancellation token, since I am debugging the `RunAsync()`, and it doesn't stuck, it simply didn't get a cancellation request.

Any Ideas?
Is it possible that the tasks I am creating are causing it? I cant see how, although if I remove these tasks, it looks that it is working as expected.
Even if the tasks are blocking, the `RunAsync()` doesn't wait for them, and should be canceled, but it doesn't.

Thanks.

```
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StateManagerHolder.Instance = StateManager;
        while (true)
        {  
            Task.Run(() => DoSomething(), cancellationToken);
            await Task.Delay(45, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the cancellationToken is cancelled, the loop would continue to run, because you didn't check if the token has been cancelled to leave the loop!

Comment: By the way, do you really need to call DoSomething() on every loop?

Comment: 1. The problem is that the CT is not cancelled.
2. The loop would be stopped, as Task.Delay will throw 'task was canceled' exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seems to be in one of my tasks which stores the state using the IReliableDictionary, as if I comment this out, it works as expected.

Since i don't know what am I doing wrong (doing a simple transaction like the docs), and according to: 
https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1139

I decided to convert the service to stateless and use Azure table.
Of course I am not experiencing this problem now!